# show last value for period as total

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Instead of showing the sum for the period, how can my table display every FW and the values, but not sum the values for the total and list the last FW for said period as the final amount?

For example, it would show the values in Red as the Periods total

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In M, you can use this to grab the last values

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Period"}, {{"data", each Table.LastN(Table.Sort(_,{{"MTD", Order.Ascending}}),1), type table }}),
List = List.Difference(List.Union(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows" [data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),{"Period"}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

Then remove any unwanted columns

[image]